# ¿Como puedo enviar mensajes automaticamente a contactos determinados en Android?

Tags: android

Necesito realizar una aplicación tipo "Boton de panico" que envie un mensaje automaticamente a contactos determinados, necesito ayuda por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido. Probablemente varias personas sepan hacer lo que pides, pero solo responderán cuando muestres qué intentaste e investigaste. Así que carga el código y haz el [tour] y mira [ask] para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.